# In excel, how can I split value in a cell and apply vlookup formula for each split value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling to find an answer for several hours and I am sort of giving up. Here is what I am doing in excel.

For each number (1 through 4) , I am assigning a code and a corresponding Score. 
I am inputting this data starting from first row (A1 through C4)

```
Number  Code    Score
 1      A        2
 2      B        4
 3      C        6
 4      D        8
```

Input: Now, each person gets a number every week and my data is like this

```
Person     Week1                    Week2
Person1     3 (A10 is the cell)       4 (A11 is the cell)
```

My output: I am using vlookup to find the value for each week and get a score.

```
Person     Week1     Week2
Person1    6         8
```

So to get 6, I am using the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A10,Complexity!A1:C4,3)
```

To get 8, I am using the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A11,Complexity!A1:C4,3)
```

So far so good. My problem is that , some week might have 2 values. 
Example:

```
Person     Week1                    
Person1     3,4 (A10 is the cell)
```

I am expecting the output score:

```
Person     Week1    
Person1    14
```

How can I split the values in the cell and apply vlookup formula for each time so i can get a total of 6 + 8

Comment: is it a limit of some week having a maximum of two values?  Will the  values always be separated in the same manner? (coma with no space, or coma with a space)

Comment: A week can have as many comma separated values. My actual production data generally has around 10 values comma separated.

Comment: You will need a VBA solution that will split the cell for you based on the coma delimiter since the maximum number of values within the cell is undefined.  With only 2-4 numbers you could do it with a formula but after that it gets cumbersome.

Comment: Actually a non-VBA solution is available. I will post it and leave it to the OP to decide whether it is too "cumbersome" for their liking.

Comment: @XORLX AWESOME!  looking forward to it!  Curious how you iterate the cell an undefined number of times.

Comment: That is possible, but then why not approach it from the other perspective, i.e. search for each value from the table in the Complexity sheet within the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `A11`, and assuming that any separator within that cell, if present, is only ever a single comma (no space), as in your examples:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&Complexity!A$1:A$4&",",","&A11&","))),Complexity!C$1:C$4)`

Copy down to give similar results for entries in `A12`, `A13`, etc. (though note that I made the reference to the *Complexity* sheet in the above absolute with respect to rows).

Regards

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are sandwhiching the value from the number column of the first table between two comas, and then asking it if it finds it in the day of the week inputs.  Does the , act as a while card?  just trying to figure out how it evaluates to true when you are searching for ,4, when the value in the week is 4  or 3,4 no trailing comas?

Comment: And BTW, I am loving the approach, just trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @ForwardEd The commas may not strictly be necessary in this case, though in general they are. Without them, for example, searching for e.g. "4" within a string which contained "2, 3, 14" would return a positive, though clearly this might be an undesirable result. Surrounding each search string with commas prevents this. Of course, we must also do so with the string being searched, else, for example, a search for ",3," or ",4," within "3,4" would fail; using ",3,4," we would guarantee success in both cases.

Comment: Sorry I missed the adding of the comas around what you were searching in.  Hence my confusion.  I went coma blind with the &",",","&. Love the solution by taking it from the other direction!

Comment: @ForwardEd Cheers!